# Avoid using Docker with Serverless Offline and Golang

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, serverless-offline

Currently, every time I need to use `serverless offline`, I have to set my function handler in `serverless.yml` to the `main.go` of the function as such:

```
hello:
    handler: src/hello/main.go
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 5
    events:
        - httpApi:
              path: /hello
              method: get
    iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
              - 'dynamodb:GetItem'
          Resource: !GetAtt DeviceTable.Arn
```

But keeping this breaks AWS Lambda and I have to change it back to `bin/hello`.

A solution is to use `serverless offline --useDocker` but testing functions that is running in Docker takes more than 30s, which is super slow.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compile your go code to binary files then run the serverless offline command.

You can create a `Makefile` to create some alias command. ex

```
.PHONY: build clean deploy deploy-local

build: clean
    @env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/hello src/hello/main.go

clean:
    @rm -rf ./bin

deploy-local: build
    @sls offline

deploy: clean build
    @sls deploy --verbose
```

Then, you can run `make deploy-local` to start serverless offline server